# How do we directly import an attributre's(column's) values in a csv file as the axes values in the plot?

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am working on a project that requires me to use  the CSV file information (`Label,Date`) directly in R to generate plots. Because the CSV file is big, I can't manually enter  those values in R. I would like to have my X-axis as `Date` and my `Y-axis` as a label (a number that varies from 1 to 5).

A part of the CSV data is here:

```
2,Fri Jan 17 10:11:16 +0000 2014,
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most of the basic R tutorials explain the `read.csv()` function pretty well. You can look it up from the R console via `?read.csv`. That will give you a data frame where you can do data trasnfomation & plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `rownames()` and `colnames()` functions once you have already imported the file using `read.csv()`.